Is there a way I can add a % sign to my results
I am currently calculating percentages for my data set:
How can I add the % symbol at the end of the numbers?

round((df.value_counts('label')/df.value_counts('label').sum()) * 100)

results:

label
retained    82.0
churned     18.0
dtype: float64


I am expecting to see % at the end of 82 and 18.

you can use the .format function to achieve this

try:
round((df.value_counts('label') / df.value_counts('label').sum()) * 100).astype(str) + '%'

